# iOS valueForKeyPath: NSstring not working

Tags: ios, nsstring, nsdictionary

I'm trying to get the values of dictionary using the value of nsstring. But is not working :

```
NSString *myPath = [[@"root." stringByAppendingString:subpath]autorelease];
NSDictionary *content = [xmlContent valueForKeyPath:myPath];
```

if I used `@"...."` it works just fine. Any of you knows why doesn't work? or if is alternative way of doing this?

working:

```
NSDictionary *content = [xmlContent valueForKeyPath:@"root.subpath"];
```

I really appreciate your help

Comment: What is the content of `subpath` in `NSString *myPath = [[@"root." stringByAppendingString:subpath]autorelease];`

Comment: `stringByAppendingString` returns an autoreleased object, you should not `autorelease` that again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking for:

```
NSString *myPath      = [@"root." stringByAppendingString:@"subpath"];
NSDictionary *content = [xmlContent valueForKeyPath:myPath];
```

or use:

```
NSString  *subpath    = @"subpath";
NSString *myPath      = [@"root." stringByAppendingString:subpath];
NSDictionary *content = [xmlContent valueForKeyPath:myPath];
```

Comment: that is exactly what I have in my post.

Comment: @Juan: in your code `subpath` is an object of NSString (Probably) did you assigned anything to it ?

Comment: po subpath
$5 = 0x00822d34 subpath . subpath is not null

Comment: @Juan: Ok, I'm not talking about memory allocated or not, is there any content ? even if the content is @"", there will be a memory, it doesn't mean that you have correct data. put NSLog(@"Yeah : %@",subpath);

Comment: @Juan: did you get any output ?